# How can I change power off function on my android

Tags: android

How can I tweak the power off option when the power button is pressed on samsung galaxy note 2? I tried different programs but none of them is working. I want that when power off option is clicked, it shows an animation or (fake shutting down). I don't want my phone to really turn off. But I want to achieve that from the power button on the phone not just an icon that I can click. Also, is there any program I can remove power off option from the list?

Is it possible to do that? I have been trying for the past few weeks, but i wasn't lucky.

Comment: It's impossible even in Home button for security reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tweak the power off option when the power button is pressed on samsung galaxy note 2?

Download the Android source code, alter it as you see fit, convert the compiled result into a ROM mod, then install the ROM mod on your device.

> Also, is there any program I can remove power off option from the list?

Download the Android source code, alter it as you see fit, convert the compiled result into a ROM mod, then install the ROM mod on your device.